# iframe embed video with php variable as source not working

Tags: php

I have a variable that stores an array, and in that array there is a YouTube url.

When I var dump

```
$node->field_video_link
```

It looks like the following:

```
array(1) { ["und"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["video_url"]=> string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC9BgH_L29c" ["thumbnail_path"]=> string(61) "public://video_embed_field_thumbnails/youtube/SC9BgH_L29c.jpg" ["video_data"]=> string(34) "a:1:{s:7:"handler";s:7:"youtube";}" ["embed_code"]=> NULL ["description"]=> NULL } } }
```

Now, I want to use the video link as an iframe so that users can watch through the site and I did it like the following:

```
$sample1_video_link = (isset($node->field_video_link['und'])) ? file_create_url($node->field_video_link['und'][0]['video_url']) : '';

<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="<?php print $sample1_video_link; ?>">
</iframe>
```

When I go view the page, the video thumbnail does not appear, and instead, I see a message that says "www.youtube.com refused to establish connection"

However, if I grab a random URL from youtube, the iframe works.

The error looks like in the below image:

[image]

Anything I am possibly doing wrong?

EDITED:

I now use echo instead of print and when I reload the page, still the same error.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $sample1_video_link; ?>"></iframe>
```

When I inspect the page, I see the following:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC9BgH_L29c"></iframe>
```

Which is apparently the same value being stored in the array.

Comment: What does `file_create_url` do? I'm not familiar with that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use echo instead of print:

```
src="<?php echo $sample1_video_link; ?>">
```

also youtube generates embedding url (share below the video) use that one instead they also generate an example iframe structure :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SC9BgH_L29c" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

going by your code you can jsut add the video id after "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"

or

```
src="<?php echo str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","https://www.youtube.com/embed/",$sample1_video_link; ?>">
```

Comment: Or the shorthand version  `<?= $sample1_video_link ?>`

Comment: I still see exactly the same error if I echo the variable

Comment: youtube generates embedding links maybe this helps : https://www.youtube.com/embed/SC9BgH_L29c

Comment: I added to my answer as well

Comment: I cannot use the url directly in the html. It needs to come from the variable as it is because its dynamic content.

Comment: how do you get the url of the video ? if it is hardcoded somewhere you can replace every occurance of a youtube url with its aequivalent embedding url

Comment: oh i just noticed the video Id at the end is exactly the same so you can just replace every occurance of "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" with  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"

Comment: @jonathanHeindl mind sending a snippet for your last comment?

Comment: i appended it to my answer (might need string escaping)

Comment: Appreciate the support. It now works the way I want